# Disabling screen saver programatically doesn't affect the control panel?

Tags: windows, screensaver, controlpanel

I've successfully disabled the screensaver using the method described in [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126627).
The problem is that when I do this, the control panel dialog still indicates that there is an active screensaver. Nothing seems to be changed there. If the user checks it, he has no way of knowing why the screen saver doesn't work.
Is this the expected behavior? Isn't this a problem?

I'm on windows XP x64 fully patched with the latest updates.

Comment: Did you try closing and re-opening Display Properties?  Did you check regedit? (HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop)

Comment: close votes? seriously? how is this NOT programming related?

Comment: Your right shoosh, it should be moved to superuser, this question makes no sense here. No one voted to close it because of your rating ... Ahh ... The power of rep!

Comment: @Mark Tomlin, Should I expect a sysadmin to solve this Win32 API question? Did you even understand the question?

Answer (score 3):

I expect that SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE is intended for temporary suspension of the screensaver should be set to its prior value before application close. Registry munging is probably the way to effect a less transient change.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest running procmon whilst disabling the screensaver via the control panel and whilst disabling it via your app to see what's different. A quick check on my machine seems to indicate that disabling should delete the key HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\SCRNSAVE.EXE.

Comment: Tried that. There are two queries to `[HKCU/HKLM]\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop` which result in `NAME NOT FOUND` and nothing else.